# NetLogo: Exporting table results into CSV

Tags: excel, datatable, export, netlogo, behaviorspace

The objective of this model is to explore potential dispersal patterns of grey wolves in the Northern Rocky Mountains. In the model, grey wolves are given a `ph-memory` attribute which corresponds to a spatial data table.

```
extensions [ gis table csv]

wolves-own [
  ...
  ph-memory ;; wolves' patch-hunting memory, table includes the patch's hash-id (KEY) and pack-id (VALUE)
  ...   
]

to initialize-wolf  [  new-pack-id  ]
    ...
    set ph-memory     table:make
    ...
end

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-gis

  file-open (word "Ph-memory-for-run-" behaviorspace-run-number ".csv")
  ...
end

to go
  if not any? wolves [stop]
  ask wolves [    
    where-am-i
  ...
  file-write (table:to-list ph-memory)
end

to where-am-i
 let patch-hash-id ([hash-id] of patch-here)       ;;Updates the hash-id of the patch the wolf is currently on
    if not table:has-key? ph-memory patch-hash-id
    [table:put ph-memory patch-hash-id pack-id]             
end
```

When I open the Excel file to view the results, the entire table is exported into a SINGLE cell. Unfortunately, this makes data analysis moot since I cannot manipulate the data easily.

[image: excel output]

My question is: Is it possible to export the data table results into excel and have the data broken into individual cells/ discrete data pairs (e.g. [ patch-hash-id, pack-id] )? I started to manually re-format the data into columns, but this is extremely tedious!

[image: ideal results]

Does someone have a recommendation of how I can export the data in an effective manner?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two problems here.  `file-write` doesn't put a carriage return at the end of its output, so successive `file-write`s string everything on one long line.  Also, Excel expects a CSV file, one where the values on each line are separated by commas, and `table:to-list` generates a list of lists of id/value pairs, but does not separate the values with commas.  The CSV extension does that nicely with `csv:to-string`, and `file-print` provides the carriage returns. The following code should show how it all fits together.

```
extensions [table csv]
globals [ph-memory]

to setup
  clear-all
  set ph-memory table:from-list [[1 2] [3 4] [5 6]]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  file-open "c:/users/cstaelin/desktop/testfile.csv"
  file-print csv:to-string table:to-list ph-memory
  file-close
end
```

After 4 ticks the csv file looks like

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
1,2
3,4
5,6
1,2
3,4
5,6
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

and Excel opens it properly.

Comment: Thank you @Charles! I greatly appreciate your assistance